# Single Point of Failure at Service Gateway (Netflix Zuul)

Tags: java, microservices, netflix-zuul, netflix

I am try to seek advice for design implementation, for using Service Gateway at Microservice Architecture

A, B, C , D, E, F are 6 microservices.

There are 2 possible scenarios for them to inter communicate

Case 1: If I let them interact between themselves on their own

[image]

Case 2: If I use a service Gateway for their communication

[image]

Service Gateway planned to be used is Netflix Zuul

My concern is the **SINGLE POINT OF Faiiilure** at Service Gateway.

*If my Service Gateway(Netflix Zuul) goes down, all the microservices will stop interacting*

Although, as this is a theoretically accepted architecture, trying seek advice for my fear!

Between Case 1 vs Case 2, what should be preferred, for a set of around 6 microservices ?

Answer (score 1):

Both the Cases have their own pros and cons. 
Mostly industries prefer second approach as having a Service Gateway or to say a API Gateway resolves many problems like security, service discovery and many more. Also a single point of failure for Zuul is not of much concern as you can use multiple instances of Zuul(may be 2) and load balance them, that solve your problem for single point of failure.

Take first case into consideration, you lack of having a single point security, you have to provide Microservices level security(like OAuth2).
Also a common design pattern that is used widely for failures and timeouts is **Hystrix**. 
You can always use that while implementing the first approach.

I think that might help...!!